# I found a mistake in old pushed commit. How can I change it and apply to later commits?

Tags: git

I have the following history:

```
0---1---2---HEAD
```

And I found that commit `0` have an error. Now I want to fix it and apply this fix to commits `1`, `2` and `HEAD`.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: You can rebase, but why don't you fix the code and make a new commit?

Comment: Have the changes been pushed to a remote repository yet? If so, just commit.

Comment: The [`--fixup` and `--autosquash`](http://fle.github.io/git-tip-keep-your-branch-clean-with-fixup-and-autosquash.html) features may come in handy here. Be aware of the [consequences of history rewriting](https://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html#_rebase_peril), though.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, @coredump I'm writing some programming tutorial and the idea was to add features to the program. I.e. commit `0` have a base functionality, commit `2` adds a new feature. And I wanted the user to be able to checkout needed commit, that's it. But I found a bug in the very first (base) commit that was pushed already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new branch from 0, apply your fixes, and rebase the old branch onto the new one. You can then use `rebase -i` to squash the fix into 0.

More recent git versions support `--fixup` commits, so you can just create one with the fixes, then do `rebase -i --autosquash` and resolve the conflicts.

Note that you shouldn't change history if the branch has already been pushed, and definitely not without agreement of other developers using the same branch.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you to explain in detail why do we need to rebase twice? Maybe with a diagram before-after?

Comment: This would have been a better solution
http://fle.github.io/git-tip-keep-your-branch-clean-with-fixup-and-autosquash.html